# Parameter not found: tessedit_create_txt

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm trying to run a simple test with python tesseract but getting an error:

```
TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, u'read_params_file: parameter not found: tessedit_create_txt')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can we see some more of your code perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove all installed versions of tesseract and install the only one. This was something about Environment variables.